# "run over to me", "run to me" and "run towards me"

Tags: meaning

> Don't let your dog run over to me.
>
> Don't let your dog run to me.
>
> Don't let your dog run towards me.

What are the differences?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume that others did so for the brevity of the question. Consider adding information about what exactly confuses you, what you you think might be the correct answer to your question, and what steps you've taken to answer the question on your own. The additional information is not only likely to improve the rating of your question but may also invite better and faster answers. https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tashus - But I already got the answer.

Comment: Your question can still be improved (and voted on) after an answer is accepted, and the advice applies to future questions as well.

Comment: @Tashus - I don't know how I can improve this question. Besides merely having these three similar expressions on my mind I had no idea what the differences between them were and my only step taken for answering this question was merely posting it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Run to me" and "run over to me" mean approximately the same thing. "Over" is redundant but emphasizes the direction of motion.

"Towards me" means "in my direction" but does not explicitly mean that the dog will reach the person. However, in this context the person is most likely concerned about the dog reaching them, so the destination is implied.